# Как войти в GitLab в первый раз?

Tags: gitlab

Поставил себе GitLab сервер дома. Поиграться.
Открываю страницу, на которой он должен быть, а там "Введите новый пароль" и "Повторите пароль".
Ну я ввёл. Пароль, естественно, записал. Только толку с него без логина????

Собственно вопрос: как мне попасть в мой же GitLab? Пытаюсь регистрироваться, а он (*как издевается*) к администратору меня посылает.

Comment: Административный интерфейс GitLab доступен через веб. Просто направьте ваш браузер на имя или IP-адрес хоста, где установлен GitLab, и войдите как администратор. Имя пользователя по умолчанию admin@local.host, пароль по умолчанию 5iveL!fe (вас попросят изменить их при входе)

Comment: Скажите, а вместо local.host должно быть имя хоста, которое я дал ему при установке Linux? Или домен, под которым я захожу в gitlab?

Comment: попробуйте admin@local.host и root@local.host

Comment: Не помогло. Самое интересное, что пароль он меня, похоже, менять просил. И я пароль знаю. Я логина не знаю.

Comment: @МихайлуцЮрий попробуйте логин root

Comment: @de_frag, Урааа. Спасибо. Это помогло. Не могли бы Вы официально ответить на данный вопрос, что бы я мог отметить Ваш ответ как правильный. Вдруг эту информацию ещё кто-то искать будет?